# Parsing element content to create HTML table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to parse data in the below format into 3 fields. Field 1 is the section number. Field 2 is the title after the section number leading up to the next period. Field 3 is all the remaining data (if there is any) before the next section number.

> 3.2.2 The contractor shall provide demonstrated understanding and application of systems engineering and configuration management principals and process,
>   mission planning/scheduling along with experience in systems engineering and sustainment of existing baseline, effectively conduct face-to-face interaction
>   with customers and other contractors to respond to requests for information, support to technical meetings, technical interchanges and enterprise working
>   groups. The contractor shall work independently and represent the program at meetings and working groups with Government and associate contractors. The
>   contractor will support customer needs and support the customer in developing them into Business/Technical Requirements and establishing scope and schedule
>   parameters to execute projects.
>   3.2.3 Design and installation of network extensions and cabling to support continued space conversions, including materials for NSWCPD buildings including
>   4, 1000, 29, 77L/H, 87, etc.

I've tried regex and looping character by character. Just wondering if there is a more efficient way.

```js
String.prototype.lines = function() {
  return this.split(/\r*\n/);
}
String.prototype.lineCount = function() {
  return this.lines().length;
}

$("#btnSave").on('click', function() {
  var textToParse = $("#textToParse").html();
  var allTRsAndTDs = "";

  // use regex or loop to generate parsed example loop only
  var iNumLines = $("#textToParse").lines().length;

  for (i = 1; i < iNumLines; i++) {
    allTRsAndTDs += `<tr>
      <td class="pws-section-id">1.1.1</td>
      <td class="title">This is the main title</td>
      <td class="description">Here is the remaining description</td>
    </tr>`;
  }

  $("#tableParsedRows").html(allTRsAndTDs);
});
```

```css
#textToParse { width: 100%; min-height: 120px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <textarea id="textToParse">
3.1 Task area 1: Network Operation and Maintenance Services
3.1.1 The contractor shall provide the necessary labor and material to provide operation and maintenance services for a RDT&E network that supports data,
voice, and video applications. The network employs Ethernet, optical, and wireless technologies. The services include operating, maintaining, securely
configuring, patching, troubleshooting and diagnostic testing of network equipment and network routing protocols to determine the cause of network
problems/failures and repairing those problems/failures in a timely manner. Troubleshooting and repair services are required on all the network equipment
which includes, but is not limited to, file servers, blade servers, communications servers, routers, bridges, switches, firewalls, Virtual Private Networks (VPN),
power supplies, modems, Uninterrupted Power Supply (UPSs), network interface cards, and cable plant (twisted pair and fiber). Approximately 2,000 devices
are connected and communicate on the network. Contractor shall:
· Troubleshoot - identify network issues based on a variety of tools / methods (e.g. packet captures, specific device (firewalls) connection logging, Cisco
CMC, Cisco FMC, monitoring tools, NAC, 802.1x, & ASDM)


3.2 Task Area 2: Engineering
3.2.1 The contractor shall provide engineering services to support the overall network architecture and data, voice, and video applications operating on the
network. Engineering services to include: review and analysis of application requirements; engineering planning and design assistance; equipment and
component recommendation, and screening for standards compliance; installation and testing support to include verification and validation; documentation
preparation /review/analysis; engineering-level monitoring of the network which includes such things as determining cause of slowed network traffic, predicting
bottlenecks in advance, resolving address conflicts, improve design to virtual LAN architecture to ensure performance and enforce Government provided
security controls.
3.2.2 The contractor shall provide demonstrated understanding and application of systems engineering and configuration management principals and process,
mission planning/scheduling along with experience in systems engineering and sustainment of existing baseline, effectively conduct face-to-face interaction
with customers and other contractors to respond to requests for information, support to technical meetings, technical interchanges and enterprise working
groups. The contractor shall work independently and represent the program at meetings and working groups with Government and associate contractors. The
contractor will support customer needs and support the customer in developing them into Business/Technical Requirements and establishing scope and schedule
parameters to execute projects.
3.2.3 Design and installation of network extensions and cabling to support continued space conversions, including materials for NSWCPD buildings including
4, 1000, 29, 77L/H, 87, etc.
3.2.4 Server/Desktop Administration – UNIX/Linux Administration and Zone D Cybersecurity Compliance. Tasks include the installation; configuration;
integration; user-registration; execution of file backups; troubleshooting and problem resolution for all Linux Systems.
3.2.5 Support architecture, design, development, utilization, authorization, maintenance of, and migration to Department of Navy authorized cloud system
providers where approved by management.
3.2.6 Gather requirements via a formalized approach for requirements (i.e., Cloud, collaborations tools, DevOps, network connectivity, high performance
computing, etc.)
3.2.7 Identify Department of Navy authorized offerings (NR&DE Cloud, DISA, Cloud, etc.)
  </textarea>
  <div class="text-center" style="margin-top:25px; margin-bottom:25px">
    <input type="submit" id="btnSave" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You are using a textarea, wouldn't you use: `$("#textToParse").val()` to get the value of the form field?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Restructured the sections array to be an array of section objects rather than a string.

You need to store a temporary section in a buffer. If you detect a new section, save the section in the buffer and initialize a new buffer.

After you scan all the rows, check if you need to save again. Then construct the rows from the sections you created.

```js
const sectionRegex = /^\d+(?:\.\d+)*[ \t]+\S.*$/m;
const titleRegex   = /^(\d+\.\d+) (.+)$/;
const topicRegex   = /(\d+\.\d+\.\d+) (.+)$/;

$('#btnSave').on('click', function() {
  var sections = [], buffer = null;

  $('#textToParse').val().split(/\r*\n/).forEach(line => {
    if (line.match(sectionRegex)) {
      if (buffer != null) {
        sections.push($.extend({}, buffer)); // Save the buffer (copy of)
      }
    
      var title = line.match(titleRegex);
      if (title) {
        buffer = { // Initialize a new buffer
          num : title[1],
          title   : title[2],
          description : []
        }
      } else {
        var topic = line.match(topicRegex);        
        if (topic) {
          buffer = { // Initialize a new buffer
            num : topic[1],
            title   : '',
            description : [ topic[2] ]
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      buffer.description.push(line); // Add to the buffer
    }
  });
  
  if (buffer.description.length > 0) {
    sections.push(buffer); // Save the buffer
  }
  
  // Construct table rows (joined description lines with a line-break)
  $('#tableParsedRows').empty().append(sections.map(section => `<tr>
      <td class="pws-section-id">${section.num}</td>
      <td class="title">${section.title}</td>
      <td class="description">${section.description.join('<br>')}</td>
    </tr>`));
});
```

```css
#textToParse { width: 100%; min-height: 120px; }

.result-table table,
.result-table td,
.result-table th {
  border: thin solid black;
}
.result-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="textToParse">
3.1 Task area 1: Network Operation and Maintenance Services
3.1.1 The contractor shall provide the necessary labor and material to provide operation and maintenance services for a RDT&E network that supports data,
voice, and video applications. The network employs Ethernet, optical, and wireless technologies. The services include operating, maintaining, securely
configuring, patching, troubleshooting and diagnostic testing of network equipment and network routing protocols to determine the cause of network
problems/failures and repairing those problems/failures in a timely manner. Troubleshooting and repair services are required on all the network equipment
which includes, but is not limited to, file servers, blade servers, communications servers, routers, bridges, switches, firewalls, Virtual Private Networks (VPN),
power supplies, modems, Uninterrupted Power Supply (UPSs), network interface cards, and cable plant (twisted pair and fiber). Approximately 2,000 devices
are connected and communicate on the network. Contractor shall:
· Troubleshoot - identify network issues based on a variety of tools / methods (e.g. packet captures, specific device (firewalls) connection logging, Cisco
CMC, Cisco FMC, monitoring tools, NAC, 802.1x, & ASDM)


3.2 Task Area 2: Engineering
3.2.1 The contractor shall provide engineering services to support the overall network architecture and data, voice, and video applications operating on the
network. Engineering services to include: review and analysis of application requirements; engineering planning and design assistance; equipment and
component recommendation, and screening for standards compliance; installation and testing support to include verification and validation; documentation
preparation /review/analysis; engineering-level monitoring of the network which includes such things as determining cause of slowed network traffic, predicting
bottlenecks in advance, resolving address conflicts, improve design to virtual LAN architecture to ensure performance and enforce Government provided
security controls.
3.2.2 The contractor shall provide demonstrated understanding and application of systems engineering and configuration management principals and process,
mission planning/scheduling along with experience in systems engineering and sustainment of existing baseline, effectively conduct face-to-face interaction
with customers and other contractors to respond to requests for information, support to technical meetings, technical interchanges and enterprise working
groups. The contractor shall work independently and represent the program at meetings and working groups with Government and associate contractors. The
contractor will support customer needs and support the customer in developing them into Business/Technical Requirements and establishing scope and schedule
parameters to execute projects.
3.2.3 Design and installation of network extensions and cabling to support continued space conversions, including materials for NSWCPD buildings including
4, 1000, 29, 77L/H, 87, etc.
3.2.4 Server/Desktop Administration – UNIX/Linux Administration and Zone D Cybersecurity Compliance. Tasks include the installation; configuration;
integration; user-registration; execution of file backups; troubleshooting and problem resolution for all Linux Systems.
3.2.5 Support architecture, design, development, utilization, authorization, maintenance of, and migration to Department of Navy authorized cloud system
providers where approved by management.
3.2.6 Gather requirements via a formalized approach for requirements (i.e., Cloud, collaborations tools, DevOps, network connectivity, high performance
computing, etc.)
3.2.7 Identify Department of Navy authorized offerings (NR&DE Cloud, DISA, Cloud, etc.)
</textarea>
<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" />
<table class="result-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Section</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tableParsedRows"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. This fit perfectly into what i needed. I implemented the code here: http://www.mazenttech.com/capability-matrix-tool/parse-pws.php. You will notice the titles aren't getting populated for the most part.  I am trying to blend your code with the regex from @sln to parse everything the way i need it. Once I am done, the data will feed into this tool http://www.mazenttech.com/capability-matrix-tool/ so it should be pretty cool

Answer (score 0):

***Updated***
Based strictly on your specifications it's this
Requires at least ***`NUMBER dot NUMBER`*** as a base section delimiter.
Can be more ***`dot NUMBER`***'s added on to the base section.

`/(?:\s|^)(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)\s+(?:((?:\([^)]*?\)|(?!\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)+\s|$)[^.])*)(?:\.((?:(?!\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)+\s|$)[\S\s])+))?)?/`

https://regex101.com/r/c5l373/1

Readable regex

```
 (?: \s | ^ )
 (                             # (1 start)
      \d+ 
      (?: \. \d+ )+
 )                             # (1 end)
 \s+ 
 (?:
      (                             # (2 start)
           (?:
                \( [^)]*? \)
             |  (?!
                     \s+ \d+ 
                     (?: \. \d+ )+
                     \s 
                  |  $
                )
                [^.]
           )*
      )                             # (2 end)
      (?:
           \.
           (                             # (3 start)
                (?:
                     (?!
                          \s+ \d+ 
                          (?: \. \d+ )+
                          \s 
                       |  $
                     )
                     [\S\s]
                )+
           )                             # (3 end)
      )?
 )?
```

JS Demo

```js
var section = [];
var title = [];
var body = [];

// Using just a partial textarea sample ...

var text = "3.2 Task Area 2: Engineering\n" +
"3.2.1 The contractor shall provide engineering services to support the overall network architecture and data, voice, and video applications operating on the\n" +
"network. Engineering services to include: review and analysis of application requirements; engineering planning and design assistance; equipment and\n" +
"component recommendation, and screening for standards compliance; installation and testing support to include verification and validation; documentation\n" +
"preparation /review/analysis; engineering-level monitoring of the network which includes such things as determining cause of slowed network traffic, predicting\n" +
"bottlenecks in advance, resolving address conflicts, improve design to virtual LAN architecture to ensure performance and enforce Government provided\n" +
"security controls.\n" +
"3.2.2 The contractor shall provide demonstrated understanding and application of systems engineering and configuration management principals and process,\n" +
"mission planning/scheduling along with experience in systems engineering and sustainment of existing baseline, effectively conduct face-to-face interaction\n" +
"with customers and other contractors to respond to requests for information, support to technical meetings, technical interchanges and enterprise working\n" +
"groups. The contractor shall work independently and represent the program at meetings and working groups with Government and associate contractors. The\n" +
"contractor will support customer needs and support the customer in developing them into Business/Technical Requirements and establishing scope and schedule\n" +
"parameters to execute projects.\n" +
"3.2.3 Design and installation of network extensions and cabling to support continued space conversions, including materials for NSWCPD buildings including\n" +
"4, 1000, 29, 77L/H, 87, etc.\n" +
"3.2.4 Server/Desktop Administration – UNIX/Linux Administration and Zone D Cybersecurity Compliance. Tasks include the installation; configuration;\n" +
"integration; user-registration; execution of file backups; troubleshooting and problem resolution for all Linux Systems.\n" 
;

var re = /(?:\s|^)(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)\s+(?:((?:\([^)]*?\)|(?!\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)+\s|$)[^.])*)(?:\.((?:(?!\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)+\s|$)[\S\s])+))?)?/g;

text.replace( re, function( m, g1, g2, g3 ) {
     section.push( g1 );
     title.push( g2 );
     body.push( g3 );
    });

if ( section.length > 0 )
{
  console.log( "Sections (",section.length,") : \r\n" );
  console.log( section );
  // ----- 
  console.log( "Titles (",title.length,") : \r\n" );
  // console.log( title );
  // ----- 
  console.log( "Bodies (",body.length,") : \r\n" );
  // console.log( body );
}
else
  console.log( "No matches !" );
```

Comment: This works quite well. BTW, the website regex101 is pretty awesome. That's a really cool tool I will have to continue to use. The data we are getting as an input is unfortunately pretty fugly, so there are some things that throw it off like numbers in the description, and missing periods at the end of the title.  Here it is with all of the data of one of our examples

Comment: @ShaunO'Toole - After some fine tuning, I've come to the conclusion, you'd be better off with this modified regex. This is no simple task. I'm afraid if you tried to modify it, it would fail, but this is a high risk, high reward regex, that is or can be _nearly_ perfect given the specified major delimiter. Let me know if it needs tweaking ...

Comment: This works very nicely....some mid-description numbers still mess it up. I will see if I can tweak to refine. As you said, this is a pretty difficult bit of text to parse. Here it is with all the data. https://regex101.com/r/2TpEHU/1

Comment: @ShaunO'Toole - Ok, I'll take a look ... I see the problem. It is with a stand-alone number surrounded by whitespace. I interpret that as a section number. I could change it to require at least NUMBER period NUMBER to be considered a section number. Wanna do that ? Or I could require at least a NUMBER period, but that's getting close to _body_ type text.

Comment: Take a look https://regex101.com/r/c5l373/1 let me know, I'll change the regex in the answer. This one requires the _**NUMBER.NUMBER**_ sections. I could make it _**NUMBER.**_ sections, but this is close to body style free form text.

Comment: B-E-A utiful....Looks great on regex101.  You are the regex master. So forgive me for my ignorance. I have done simpler stuff before. Parsing this into individual variables like Mr. Polywhirl, I tried the below but it didn't work

const sectionRegex = /(?:\s|^)(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)\s/;
const titleRegex   =  /(?:\.\d+)+/;
const topicRegex   = /(?:((?:\([^)]*?\)|(?!\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)+\s|$)[^.])*)(?:\.((?:(?!\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)+\s|$)[\S\s])+))?)?/;

this is my sample page:
http://www.mazenttech.com/capability-matrix-tool/parse-pws.php

Comment: @ShaunO'Toole - Added a JS demo - shows how to get section, title, bodies into individual arrays. Each element in the respective arrays constitute a row of related information.

Comment: hi @sln. I have some data pre-populated in the textarea on http://www.mazenttech.com/capability-matrix-tool/parse-pws.php. I can't seem to figure out, the lines with the section numbers (the "section" array) aren't getting parsed to the first carriage return. All the data up to the first period are getting pulled into "section". If you look at the first 2 sections, I don't have a period at the end, and they don't get parsed correctly. For all the remaining sections, I had to add a period to the end of each line for it to get parsed correctly.  I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: `the lines with the section numbers (the "section" array) aren't getting parsed to the first carriage return`  The section array comprises elements that start with a _digit_ dot _digit_ with optional dot digits added on. There is nothing else, not letters or newlines nor nothing. The "title"  array follows the section number,  is optional,  and is all the text up to the next period. After that, is the body, and is all the way up until the next section number. Your text seems to parse correctly. https://regex101.com/r/0ZNSIz/1 Pay attention to groups 1, 2 and 3. Those are the arrays.

Comment: Also, link to specific text that shows what your problem is. And, see if the "title" specs need to be changed, like look for a period to terminate it, but stay on the first line. If no period is found on the first line as a title terminator, then a newline is ok, etc... Also, note that I don't capture the period at the end of the title. But currently, it _must_ be there as the separator between title and body, or if its not there, then don't have a body, it's all title, etc.. This can be changed though to be like I said, the title ends at the end of the first line if the period is not found.

Comment: Hi @sln, thank you for your quick response. 
The section is getting parsed correctly (the number.number.number).  The Title (Group 2) should end either at the first period or at the end of the line (carriage return that the section number was found).  In the first example the Title should only be "Navy Electronic Procurement System (ePS)". The remaining text should go into the body. I tried adding "\n" into the non-capturing group to finish on a period or a carriage return, but it isn't working for me.

Comment: this works better Group 2(the title), but I don't get Group 3(the body) https://regex101.com/r/ghtAMI/1

Comment: I'm afraid you're not going to like the output of the period or end of line regex any better https://regex101.com/r/wP3LCl/1. The problem is there is no clear way to distinguish where the title ends and the body begins.

Answer (score 0):

A huge thank you to sln & Mr. Polywhirl for helping me solve this one. The working code is below. Here is an example page that implements the regex: http://www.mazenttech.com/capability-matrix-tool/parse-pws.php

```
<div id="topContainer" class="container">


<textarea id="textToParse">
3.1 Task area 1: Network Operation and Maintenance Services
3.1.1 The contractor shall provide the necessary labor and material to provide operation and maintenance services for a RDT&E network that supports data,
voice, and video applications. The network employs Ethernet, optical, and wireless technologies. The services include operating, maintaining, securely
configuring, patching, troubleshooting and diagnostic testing of network equipment and network routing protocols to determine the cause of network
problems/failures and repairing those problems/failures in a timely manner. Troubleshooting and repair services are required on all the network equipment
which includes, but is not limited to, file servers, blade servers, communications servers, routers, bridges, switches, firewalls, Virtual Private Networks (VPN),
power supplies, modems, Uninterrupted Power Supply (UPSs), network interface cards, and cable plant (twisted pair and fiber). Approximately 2,000 devices
are connected and communicate on the network. Contractor shall:
· Troubleshoot - identify network issues based on a variety of tools / methods (e.g. packet captures, specific device (firewalls) connection logging, Cisco
CMC, Cisco FMC, monitoring tools, NAC, 802.1x, & ASDM)
· Network security – evaluate current Network Security confirmation and leverage understanding of firewall, Cisco ASA, VPN, IPSec, Routers, Fire Power,
FMC, Switches, proxy technologies concepts to suggest perimeter security concepts to Code 104 for implementation (e.g. DMZ, multi-tier security zones, etc.)
· Design and recommend improvements to the operation and maintenance of the Network Admission Control (NAC) system for use on WLAN and Virtual
Private Networking (VPN) access.
· Evaluate new wireless network hardware
· Install and support Cisco routers, core switches, Layer 2 and 3 switches, Wireless APs/sensors, VPN and firewalls (Cisco ASA series).
· Audit network access in order to comply with current DoD audit security requirements “Defense In Depth”.
· Design and configure data center LAN technologies such as Spanning Tree, EIGRP and multi-VRF solutions.
· Utilize security technologies, specifically, Bluecoat Web Content Filter Proxies, Bluecoat Reporter, and Active Directory to harden NSWCPD systems.
· Maintain accurate documentation for the installation, maintenance and configuration activities.
3.1.2 Contractor shall provide 24 by 7 emergency Network Operations support during high priority testing or processing periods (on an as needed basis). The
24 by 7 coverage will be scheduled with the contractor when testing or processing is planned and a network outage or server down time lasting until the next
business day would impact the desired testing or processing schedule. The Government Technical Point of Contact (TPOC) will request the 24 by 7 coverage a
minimum of two days in advance of the required coverage. The Government will authorize overtime for this support. The Government estimates no more than
8 weeks’ total required emergency coverage. Contractor shall:
· Develop test plans for wireless LAN Controller, lightweight and autonomous wireless access points (CDRL)
· Test and certify wireless network hardware, operating system versions and configurations
· Perform installation of security patches, remediation of vulnerabilities and reporting of patch compliance; advise on security patch management and
remediation actions
· Apply secure configurations such as DISA Secure Technical Implementation Guidance (STIG), including the documentation and retention of objective
quality evidence of the applied configuration
3.2 Task Area 2: Engineering
3.2.1 The contractor shall provide engineering services to support the overall network architecture and data, voice, and video applications operating on the
network. Engineering services to include: review and analysis of application requirements; engineering planning and design assistance; equipment and
component recommendation, and screening for standards compliance; installation and testing support to include verification and validation; documentation
preparation /review/analysis; engineering-level monitoring of the network which includes such things as determining cause of slowed network traffic, predicting
bottlenecks in advance, resolving address conflicts, improve design to virtual LAN architecture to ensure performance and enforce Government provided
security controls.
3.2.2 The contractor shall provide demonstrated understanding and application of systems engineering and configuration management principals and process,
mission planning/scheduling along with experience in systems engineering and sustainment of existing baseline, effectively conduct face-to-face interaction
with customers and other contractors to respond to requests for information, support to technical meetings, technical interchanges and enterprise working
groups. The contractor shall work independently and represent the program at meetings and working groups with Government and associate contractors. The
contractor will support customer needs and support the customer in developing them into Business/Technical Requirements and establishing scope and schedule
parameters to execute projects.
3.2.3 Design and installation of network extensions and cabling to support continued space conversions, including materials for NSWCPD buildings including
4, 1000, 29, 77L/H, 87, etc.
3.2.4 Server/Desktop Administration – UNIX/Linux Administration and Zone D Cybersecurity Compliance. Tasks include the installation; configuration;
integration; user-registration; execution of file backups; troubleshooting and problem resolution for all Linux Systems.
3.2.5 Support architecture, design, development, utilization, authorization, maintenance of, and migration to Department of Navy authorized cloud system
providers where approved by management.
3.2.6 Gather requirements via a formalized approach for requirements (i.e., Cloud, collaborations tools, DevOps, network connectivity, high performance
computing, etc.)
3.2.7 Identify Department of Navy authorized offerings (NR&DE Cloud, DISA, Cloud, etc.)
3.2.8 Develop solutions to leverage authorized offerings regarding cloud technologies
3.2.9 Research possible solutions to virtualize traditionally isolated operating systems while implementing micro-segmentation for network security
3.2.10 Provide recommended solutions to gaps between existing capabilities and departmental requirements.
3.2.11 Establish POA&M addressing short, mid and long term solutions
3.2.12 Develop Change Management, provisioning, and management processes and associated documentation
3.2.13 Identify success criteria regarding cloud deployments
3.2.14 Determine cloud best fits for existing products, and a roadmap to move those projects to cloud deployment over a number of years
3.2.15 Work closely with network Infrastructure and RMF accreditation teams to overcome roadblocks to cloud deployment.
3.2.16 Align cloud deployments to DoD/DON IT security and infrastructure requirements
3.3 Task Area 3: Design/Installation of Network Extensions and Enhancements Services
3.3.1 The contractor shall design, install, test, and validate both network extensions and
modifications. The design shall include installation drawings that show the proposed cable and equipment closet. The design shall include locations and list of
materials required to complete the task. Upon approval, the contractor will provide materials and schedule technicians to perform work within agreed upon time
frame. The design shall be compatible with the electrical, physical, and environmental limitations of the site. The contract shall be aware of red/black
separation requirements for mixed classification environments, such as TEMPEST. The contractor shall conduct validation testing and review installer test
reports after the installation of a network extension to determine compliance with the design/contract specifications and report any discrepancy to the technical
point of contact (TPOC) for further action.
3.4 Task Area 4: Telecommunications Services
3.4.1 The contractor shall provide engineering services for obtaining and troubleshooting various capacity leased lines and associated equipment such as
cellular repeating devices, line monitors, smart jacks, and ISDN components. The contractor shall assist in provisioning new service: submitting Requests for
Service (RFS), Telecommunications Service Requests (TSR’s) and research Delayed Service Reports (DSR’s) when necessary. Collect, develop, and document
new long-haul requirements. Ensure all circuit information is current and no inadvertent interruption of service occurs. Prepare circuit diagrams, update service
agreements, and keep long-haul management folders on file for inspections and for troubleshooting purposes. Coordinate discontinued action on circuits no
longer required by the Government. Maintain inventory of circuits.
3.5 Task Area 5: Server/Desktop Administration
3.5.1 The contractor shall provide the necessary labor to provide RDT&E and NMCI server/desktop administration for approximately 75 servers and Desktop
Support for approximately 2500 workstations at the Philadelphia Division. Server/Desktop system administration shall include the following:
3.5.2 Provide installation, configuration, troubleshooting, patching, and problem resolution for client workstations.
3.5.3 Provide installation, configuration, troubleshooting, problem resolution and backups of VMware virtual infrastructure; tasks include:
3.5.3.1 Configuration of VMware components for connectivity and use;
3.5.3.2 Perform in-depth troubleshooting and problem analysis on a daily basis with all action steps documented each time in a trouble ticket system;
3.5.3.3 Provide patch and update management services;
3.5.3.4 Support the evolution of current architecture and processes to enable rapid, affordable, secure delivery and lifecycle support of IT products and services
that meet the operational needs;
3.5.3.5 Maintain responsibility for Storage Area Networks (SAN) consolidation and optimization efforts;
3.5.3.6 Support configuration change documentation and control processes and maintaining DOD STIG Compliance.
3.5.4 Providing installation, configuration, integration, user registration, file backups,troubleshooting and problem resolution for servers associated with network
operations infrastructure servers, and corporate applications.
3.5.5 Providing installation, configuration, integration, file backups, troubleshooting and problem resolution for Storage Area Networks.
3.5.6 Providing installation, configuration, integration, user registration, file backups, security patches, troubleshooting and problem resolution for collaborate
environment, i.e, SharePoint, Plexus, Team Environment, and/or Lotus Notes.
3.5.7 Administration, configuration, backup and restore and problem resolution for database servers.
3.5.8 Installation of security patches on servers, remediation of vulnerabilities and reporting of patch compliance. Advise on security patches and remediation.
Tasks include:
3.5.8.1 Patch vulnerabilities within the environment to ensure information is safeguarded against unauthorized access or tampering.
3.5.8.2 Ensure application of security patches for commercial products integrated into system design meet the timelines dictated by the management authority
for the intended operational environment.
3.5.8.3 Integrate automated capabilities for updating or patching system software where practical, and develop processes and procedures for manual system
software updating and patching using current and projected patch timeline requirements for the system’s operational environment.
3.5.8.4 Determine and document critical numbers of software patches or the extent of releases that would leave software vulnerable.
3.5.8.5 Operate and maintain the Assured Compliance Assessment Solution (ACAS)
3.5.8.6 Provide system administration and maintain operations of Nessus and Security Center.
3.5.8.7 Maintain system patches, O/S, Database, and Application STIG compliance
3.5.8.8 Update ACAS plugin Libraries, in accordance with Dept. of Navy requirements
3.5.8.9 Resolve Security Center web interface issues and Nessus network scanning issues
3.5.8.10 Configure and manage ACAS application level for user permissions, policies, scan zones, and repositories
3.5.9 Assisting the Government in managing life cycle requirements.
3.5.10 Performing routine audits of systems and software, adding, removing, or updating user accounts information, resetting passwords.
3.5.11 Answering technical queries, maintaining security posture, monitor system security, documenting system configuration, and conduct performance tuning.
3.5.12 Supporting servers and Windows Active Directory domain for PKI authentication. Support use of alternate authentication procedures for
administrative access to servers.
3.5.13 Supporting configuration change documentation and control processes
3.5.14 Apply secure configurations (e.g. DISA Secure Technical Implementation Guidance (STIG)), including the documentation and retention of objective
quality evidence of the applied configuration
3.5.15 Analyze event logs on all servers and apply corrective actions when necessary to ensure all servers are operational
3.5.16 Perform routine audits of server systems; adding, removing, or updating user accounts information; resetting passwords
3.5.17 Troubleshoot user problems to determine whether they are hardware, software, procedural, or communication related and provide timely resolution
3.5.18 Log and track service desk tickets using NSWCCD Philadelphia Help Desk software; maintain historical records and related problem documentation
3.5.18.1 Address all assigned service desk tickets in a timely and efficient manner
3.5.18.2 Document instances of server equipment or component failure, repair, installation, and removal using NSWCCD Philadelphia Help Desk software.
3.5.19 Monitor server systems on a daily basis to find and correct problems with disk usage, hardware, and software
3.5.20 Liaise with third-party support and server equipment vendors to resolve outstanding server issues
3.5.21 Upgrade server hardware, including memory, hard drives, external media devices (optical and non-optical), monitors, motherboards, processors, video
cards, network cards, and other special purpose cards

</textarea>
    <div class="text-center" style="margin-top:25px; margin-bottom:25px">
    <input type="submit" id="btnParse" value="Parse PWS" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" />

     <div  style="margin-top:40px">
        <table class="result-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Section</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="tableParsedRows"></tbody>
        </table>
     </div>
 </div>



<script>




$('#btnParse').on('click', function() {

    var section = [];
    var title = [];
    var body = [];
    var text = $('#textToParse').val();

    const re = /(?:\s|^)(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)\s+(?:((?:\([^)]*?\)|(?!\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)+\s|$)[^.])*)(?:\.((?:(?!\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)+\s|$)[\S\s])+))?)?/g;

    text.replace( re, function( m, g1, g2, g3 ) {
         section.push( g1 );
         title.push( g2 );
         body.push( g3 );
    });
    /*
    if ( section.length > 0 )
    {
      console.log( "Sections (",section.length,") : \r\n" );
      console.log( section );
      // ----- 
      console.log( "Titles (",title.length,") : \r\n" );
      // console.log( title );
      // ----- 
      console.log( "Bodies (",body.length,") : \r\n" );
      // console.log( body );
    }
    else{
        console.log( "No matches !" );
    }
    */

    const numEntries = section.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < numEntries; i++) {
        //console.log(section[i]);

        if (body[i] === undefined){
            body[i] = "";
        } 
        $('#tableParsedRows').append(`<tr>
                                          <td class="pws-section-id">${section[i]}</td>
                                          <td class="title">${title[i]}</td>
                                          <td class="description">${body[i]}</td>
                                    </tr>`);

    }


});






</script>
```

Comment: I hit the parse PSW button but it does not fill the table .